# Pyinstaller executable opens and immediately closes

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller, pyqtgraph

I am trying to create an executable from a python project with pyinstaller. However, when I run the executable, it just opens and closes immediately.
I don't get one error and two warnings when running pyinstaller from the command line. There are no error messages when running the executable.

(But I don't think that the two warnings should be problematic as I've created other executables with those same warnings and they still worked fine!!)

When I run

```
pyinstaller --debug=all main.py
```

I get

```
12070 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.py2_warn" not found!
12070 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.markers" not found!
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[path]/venv/bin/pyinstaller", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "[path]/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 126, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "[path]/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "[path]/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 815, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "[path]/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 762, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "[path]/main.spec", line 37, in <module>
    coll = COLLECT(exe,
  File "[path]/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/api.py", line 855, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "[path]/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 159, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "[path]/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/api.py", line 883, in assemble
    os.makedirs(todir)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 225, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '[path]/dist/main/main/GUI'
```

When I now run

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import pkg_resources.py2_warn --hidden-import pkg_resources.markers --debug=all main.py
```

I get

```
11705 ERROR: Hidden import 'pkg_resources.py2_warn' not found
11705 ERROR: Hidden import 'pkg_resources.markers' not found
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[path]/venv/bin/pyinstaller", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "[path]/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 126, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "[path]/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "[path]/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 815, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "[path]/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 762, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "[path]/main.spec", line 37, in <module>
    coll = COLLECT(exe,
  File "[path]/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/api.py", line 855, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "[path]/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 159, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "[path]/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/api.py", line 883, in assemble
    os.makedirs(todir)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 225, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '[path]/dist/main/main/GUI'
```

I've been stuck at this problem for days and at this point I really don't know what to do!

---

My system specs:

- MacOS 11.5.2
- Python 3.9
- pyinstaller 4.5.1 (Python package)
- setuptools 57.5.0 (Python package)
- PyQt5 5.15.4 (Python package)
- pyqtgraph 0.12.2 (Python package)

I am running everything in a virtual environment.

My project structure is:

```
Project  
|- dist  
|- build  
|- main.spec  
|  
|- main.py  
|- main  
|  |- GUI  
|     |- MainWindow.py  
|     |- ui.py  
|  |- Sim  
|     |- Setter.py  
|     |- Integrator.py
```

Comment: You can use [`--debug=all`](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html#getting-debug-messages) to get more error message (on the executable) during runtime

Comment: @gfdsweds I've tried that now and I do get an error message now:
`
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: './dist/main/main/GUI'
`
where ```GUI``` is a folder in my project.

Comment: I'll update my post now with the new error

Comment: Whats the line of code that it points that error to?

Comment: @Joe I've added the entire traceback in the post now

Comment: @Joe Oh I think I got it working (the executable executes) :))))

Comment: @Joe I changed the name of the package ```main``` from ```main``` to ```MainPackage```. I think the error was that my entry-point ```main.py``` had the same name as the directory ```main``` (which contains the other code that is called).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The executable works now after I changed the name of the directory `main` from `main` to `MainPackage`.

I think the error was that my entry-point `main.py` had the same name as the directory `main` (which contains the other code that is called). So pyinstaller confused the directory with the entry-point file.

Also, I didn't have to include the two hidden imports for the executable to work (as suspected). The command to build the executable is simply:

```
pyinstaller main.py
```